# How to use OpenCV train_hog.cpp

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV [train_HOG](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/train_HOG.cpp) utility.

When I try to compile it with

```
g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` train_HOG.cpp -o train_HOG
```

I get a ton of different errors.

```
train_HOG.cpp:11:21: error: ‘ml’ is not a namespace-name
 using namespace cv::ml;
                     ^
train_HOG.cpp:11:23: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
 using namespace cv::ml;
```

And a few pages more.

Can anyone give me instructions how to use it properly or point me to a working solution?

Comment: are you using opencv3 or 2.4 ?

Comment: please check, if your opencv2/ml.hpp [looks like this](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/ml/include/opencv2/ml.hpp#L74)

Comment: They are different. I was following [this](http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/) to set up.

Comment: Good option (but not the fastest one) might be to just build whole OpenCV with all applications. There is a lot of tutorials about it and this way will surely work. I know it's definitely an overkill for this little problem, but im might be the best option "for future".